# Azure AppGateway stops handling/routing connections after some time

Tags: azure, gateway

We have an Azure AppGateway set up that routes traffic to 3 of our application nodes. Recently, the App Gateway has started encountering an issue where it just stops working after a few hours - everything was fine and then it just abruptly stops receiving/handling connections. Short of setting up a new App Gateway, nothing else seems to work to get around this to get the requests going again.

And when we do set up a new App Gateway, the problem re-surfaces after a few hours and its back to square one. We have a number of App Gateways setup and the problem seems to be unique to just this one Gateway. Any advice on how we can troubleshoot this to see what's going on and get that addressed?

Comment: Anything in the logs showing a change?  Is there any automation in place that could be updating the configuration?

Comment: No, nothing in the activity logs that indicates any problems. Is there any other log we can look at to see if there are issues? And no, there is no automation in place that would be altering anything. This has been working well for a few months, the issues started just since the last couple of days and we don't believe we've changed anything